# How to get detailed language of device in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a database on the server that contains all the languages keywords that I use inside my applications and these languages could be changed any time.

In the language table of database there is `column` for `Language` `(id , key, value, lang)`.

In the android application I read the language from device and it returns for example `en-GB` or `en-US`.

But in the iOS application I can't get the language like the above example , It always returns just the language (`en , es, fr`).

So I can't query to database to get the language specified keywords on the iOS application. Because the languages on the database is en-GB, en-US style.

```
var langId: String? = NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first as? String
```

How can I get the language with more details ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start with the `currentLocale()` and ask questions about it. For example:

```
let lang = NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier
```

Or, at a finer level of granularity:

```
let langId = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as! String
let countryId = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String
let language = "\(langId)-\(countryId)" // en-US on my machine
```

Comment: If someone in France use an iPhone with English language , Your code will returns en-FR ? or en-US ?

Comment: Locale is a system setting. It has nothing to do with where the phone is located physically. Nothing about the phone magically changes just because you cross a border! If you want to know where the phone is, use Location Services.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 3** does not have an `NSLocaleCountryCode`, this is replaced by regionCode

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale.key/1417845-countrycode

solution in Swift 5.7:

```
let langCode = Locale.current.language.languageCode ?? ""
let regionCode = Locale.current.language.region ?? ""
let language = "\(langCode)-\(regionCode)"
```

Another solution is `NSLocale.current.identifier`
This will return e.g. `en_us`

You could replace `_` for `-`. it will look like this: `NSLocale.current.identifier.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "-")`

Answer (score 9):

No need an extra effort, just use the following as per your requirement.

```
Locale.current.identifier //en_US
Locale.current.collatorIdentifier //en-US
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 4** use instead:

```
NSLocale.current.identifier //Output: en-US, pt-BR
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code line can solve:

> let identifier = Locale.current.identifier

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
Locale.currentLanguage.rawValue
```