# Why Locale.current.identifier is invalid?

Tags: ios, swift, locale

The problem arises when setup the "Language & Region" (Settings => General => Language & Region) as follows:

- "iPhone Language" to "English (Canada)".
- "Region" to "Jordan".

However, (as mentioned answer for: [How to get detailed language of device in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141174/how-to-get-detailed-language-of-device-in-swift_) calling:

```
print(Locale.current.identifier)
```

Logs:

> en_JO

which is an *invalid* [local identifier](https://gist.github.com/jasef/337431c43c3addb2cbd5eb215b376179) (Logically speaking, Jordan is a Middle-East country which its native language is Arabic not English).

I also checked the [availableIdentifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293697-availableidentifiers):

```
print(Locale.availableIdentifiers)
```

and -obviously -it does *not* contains "en_JO".

Also, I tried:

```
if let regionCode = Locale.current.regionCode, let languageCode = Locale.current.languageCode {
    print("\(languageCode)_\(regionCode)")
}
```

and the output was the same.

It seems that it has nothing to do with identifier validity, but how can I make sure to get a valid identifier? As an example, in my case the expected result should be:

> en_CA

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I am curious: What is the actual problem? You have a `Locale` that you can work with. – Also `Locale(identifier: "en_JO").currencyCode` returns "JOD" in my test, so "en_JO" seems to be a recognized identifier, even if not present in the `availableIdentifiers` list.

Comment: @MartinR the actual problem that such an identifier makes [the server side to be unhappy with it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx), it is unrecognisable for it... I also tried to check "en_JO" on https://gist.github.com/jasef/337431c43c3addb2cbd5eb215b376179 and I couldn't find it...

Comment: @MartinR also, I tried to check the `Locale.availableIdentifiers` array, it does not contains "en_JO"...

Comment: That locale is not invalid. It just means there is no specific settings for it, therefore probably most settings will come only from the "en" part.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing invalid about the identifier `en_JO`. The identifier is completely valid per the Unicode standard as an identifier for English in Jordan region.

However, that does not mean data for that region has to be available. The system is not required to have data for every crazy combination of language and region.

See [Language Matching](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35.html#LanguageMatching) in the Unicode standard. If there is no data for the requested locale, a fallback locale is then used, in this case probably the locale `en`.

Comment: So, is there a no way to get the country for the selected language (which in my case is Canada)? I tried to check the properties without a useful result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, to make sure that I got it correctly: it is a valid but not available; For such a case, the `en` independently would be  the valid one, is this correct? If that's the case, I will not be able to recognize whether its available or not (unless I do it manually), I will have to always use the `Locale.current.languageCode`...

Answer (score 2):

Every locale identifier includes a language code(e.g. en) and a region code(e.g. JO). This much is evident from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW9):

> A locale ID identifies a specific region and its cultural
>   conventions—such as the formatting of dates, times, and numbers. To
>   specify a locale, use an underscore character to combine a language ID
>   with a region designator

This means your statement that en_JO is an invalid identifier is incorrect. It is formed because you have selected english as a language and region to Jordan.

Now, if you want to get only langauge part, you can get it by [preferredLangauges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293155-preferredlanguages),

```
let langId = Locale.preferredLanguages.first
```

or by [collatorIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293445-collatoridentifier) on current `Locale`

```
let langId = Locale.current.collatorIdentifier // returns optional string
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, calling `print(Locale.availableIdentifiers)` doesn't contains `en_JO` ... `languageCode` returns only "en", how can I get "en_CA"?

Comment: Also, you could check if "en_JO" exists in the https://gist.github.com/jasef/337431c43c3addb2cbd5eb215b376179 list

Comment: @AhmadF: edited the answer on how you can get the lang id

Comment: Both `preferredLanguages.first` and `Locale.current.collatorIdentifier` values are "en", without the "-CA".

Comment: It is definitely not the case when I check in my simulator. Attaching the screenshot of my simulator.